# Nginx redirect failure for icingaweb2

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to configure IcingaWeb2 using Nginx, and having some issues with it. The suggested Icinga Nginx configuration is:

```
location ~ ^/icingaweb2/index\.php(.*)$ {
  # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/icingaweb2/public/index.php;
  fastcgi_param ICINGAWEB_CONFIGDIR /etc/icingaweb2;
  fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
}

location ~ ^/icingaweb2(.+)? {
  alias /usr/share/icingaweb2/public;
  index index.php;
  try_files $1 $uri $uri/ /icingaweb2/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

This works fine, but let's the web on /icingaweb2/ while I want it on /. If I just remove icingaweb2/ from the conf, it works fine for every URL but /.

My current configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    server_name example.com
    ssl_certificate cert_path;
    ssl_certificate_key cert_key;

    location ~ ^/index\.php(.*)$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/icingaweb2/public/index.php;
      fastcgi_param ICINGAWEB_CONFIGDIR /etc/icingaweb2;
      #fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
    }

    location ~ ^/(.*)? {
     alias /usr/share/icingaweb2/public;
     index index.php;
     try_files $1 $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine if I try, for example, to access `https://example.com/dashboard` but fails only for `https://example.com/` with a **403** error. I have also tried to configure a specific `location / {}` doing a redirect o rewrite to /dashboard but still getting a 403.

Any idea of what can I try next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fix it putting a rewrite on the second location.

```
location ~ ^/(.*)? {
 alias /usr/share/icingaweb2/public;
 index index.php;
 rewrite ^/$ /dashboard;
 try_files $1 $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

It doesn't feel like the best... but now all is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition for anyone who is still facing this problem:

An additional / at the index attribute solves this.

```
location ~ ^/icingaweb2(.+)? {
  alias /usr/share/icingaweb2/public;
  index /index.php;
  try_files $1 $uri $uri/ /icingaweb2/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Happy 2020